# A [prefix] at [infix] early [suffix] can't [whole] everything

Tags: riddle, affix-riddle

> A [prefix] at [infix] early [suffix] can't [whole] everything.

What is the logical statement when the gaps are filled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This statement can be resolved as follows:

> A **MAN_** at **_AN_** early **_AGE** can't **MANAGE** everything.
>
>  Here, MAN is the prefix, AN is the infix, and AGE is the suffix. The statement rather philosophically suggests that we enter this life with a lot of learning to do!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different alternative answer

> A **MAN** at **AN** early **DATE** can't **MANDATE** everything.
>  The point being that it takes time and experience in order to provide authority to others.